# In Lumen API with passport authentication showin CORS issue in React JS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, lumen

I have created API in Lumen and authenticated by Passport, The API without auth(login API) is working fine  API but the API which has Auth middleware showing CORS issue.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's a typo mistake. and Thanks!

Comment: My question is, how to solve this CORS issue in Authenticated API?